# Command to remove the first N number of lines in input

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, tail, head

## Background

I am running an SSH server and have this user that I want to delete. I cannot delete this user because he is currently running a few processes that I need to kill first.

This is the pipeline I am using currently using to find out all the process ids of the user I am currently using:

```
ps -u user | awk '{print $1;}'
```

The output looks like this:

```
PID
2121
2122
2124
2125
2369
2370
```

I want to pipe this to `kill -9` to kill all processes so I can delete this stupid user like this:

```
ps -u user | awk '{print $1;}' | sudo xargs kill -9
```

But this does not work because of the `PID` header:

```
kill: failed to parse argument: 'PID'
```

## The question

I am thinking that there has to be a simple Unix command to remove the first line of input.

I am aware that I can use `tail` for this but I don't want to count how many lines the input contains to figure out exactly how many I want to display.

I am looking for something like `head` or `tail` but inverted (instead of displaying **only** the first/last part of the stream it displays **everything but** the start/end of stream).

## Note

I managed to solve this issue I had by simply adding `| grep [[:digit:]]` after my `awk` command but I am still looking for a way to delete first line of a file as I think would be quite useful in other scenarios.

Comment: Since you're already using awk, you could have excluded the header record (line) using `NR` e.g. `awk 'NR>1 {print $1;}'`. Better yet - use `pgrep -u` or `pkill -u`

Comment: @steeldriver Interesting! Make an answer and explain how it (the `awk` command) works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NOTE: if your system already has `pgrep`/`pkill` then you are re-inventing the wheel here. If your system doesn't have these utilities, then you should be able to format the output of `ps` to get the unencumbered PID list directly e.g. `ps -u user -opid=`**

If you are already using `awk`, there is no need to pipe through an additional process in order to remove the first line (record): simply add a condition on the record number `NR`

```
ps -u user | awk 'NR>1{print $1;}'
```

Since you mention `head` and `tail`, the formula you probably want in this case is `tail -n +2`

Comment: `tail -n +2` was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 for telling `ps` not to print a header with `-opid=`, as that prevents the output from ever showing up. If a future user ever decides to sort the `ps` output in the middle of the pipeline, the awk/sed/tail assumption may break.

Answer (score 10):

As I was writing this question I figured out a solution using `sed`.

## Delete one line at beginning of input

To delete one line use `sed 1d`.

## Delete multiple lines at beginning of input

To delete `N` number of lines use `sed 1,Nd`

- To delete the first 5 lines use `sed 1,5d`
- To delete the first 10 lines use `sed 1,10d`
- To delete the first 25 lines use `sed 1,25d`

## The pipeline

So the pipeline becomes in the scenario becomes:

```
ps -u user | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 1d | sudo xargs kill -9
                                     ^ removes the PID header
```